# Saving To-Do list data to local storage with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So if I want to save all the To-Do items in Local storage and retrieve when I restart the computer or refresh the page all the items come up on the page in their original order.?

```js
//check of spec
$("ol").on("click", "li", function(){
$(this).toggleClass("completed");

});

//click on X to delete To-DO

$("ol").on("click", "span", function(event){
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
  $(this).remove();
 });
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text'").keypress(function(event){
 if(event.which === 13) {
  //grabbing the text typed
  var todoText = $(this).val();
  $(this).val("");
  //create a new LI and add to UL
  $("ol").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText +"</li>")
 }
});

$(".fa-plus").click(function(){
 $("input[type='text'").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
h1 {
 background: #2980b9;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;

}

iframe {
 float: left;
}

ol {
 /* THE BULLET POINTS
 list-style: none;
 */
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 18px;

}

body {

 background-color: rgb(13, 168, 108);

}

li {
 background: #fff;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n){
 background: #d3d3d3;
}

span {

 height: 30px;
 width: 0px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
 opacity:0;
 background: #e74c3c
 

}

li:hover span {
 width: 30px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

input {
 font-size: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
 color: #2980b9;
 background-color: #e4e4e4;

}

input:focus {
 background: white;
 border: 3px solid green;

 /*OUTLINE OF INPUT BOX
 outlin: none; */
}

.fa-plus {
 float: right;
}


#container {
 
 width: 360px;
 margin: 60px auto;
 background: #d3d3d3;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);


}

.completed {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ToDo List</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="utd.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );

  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5zr5d5i/n1991/szw110/szh110/hoc09f/hbw0/hfc09f/cf100/hnce1ead6/fas30/fdi66/mqc000/mql15/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl15/mhw4/mhd98/mmc000/mml10/mmw1/mmd98/hhc00f/hhs2/hmcf00/hms2/hsv0" frameborder="0" width="110" height="110"></iframe>


 <div id="container">
  <h1>To-do List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
  <form id="task-list">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To-Do" id="task">
 </form>
  <ol id="sortable">
   <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> EXAMPLE</li>
   
  </ol>
 </div>

 

<script type="text/javascript" src="Utd.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry this is my first time on here and the title glitched i guess sorry

Comment: Can you edit and fix your question?  It's more than just the title that glitched.

Comment: Whats wrong with it, really sorry im new to this website

Comment: Load your question, and look at it - it's pretty obvious what's wrong :)

Comment: It looks like you pressed and held Ctrl-V...

Comment: Oh wow is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Use the 'edit', Luke...

Comment: Ok, now, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Nothing so far im waiting for a answer.

Comment: @GregMyers please clarify what exactly is not working with your code. Please review: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 2):

Happy Holidays!

Your coding wishes are granted. This is a gift, to you, and you will have to be a good person and post better examples and remember that people are not here to write code for you.

There was a LOT of stuff lacking from your example.

1. Add items to a list

   - Update local storage when items are added to a list
2. Allow list to be sorted

   - Update local storage when list is updated
3. Allow task items to be marked completed

   - Update local storage when items are completed
4. Allow task items to be deleted

   - Update local storage when tasks are deleted
5. Load locally stored tasks

I think that covers everything you wanted this script to do. Is it becoming more clear now?

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ae6oLr47/12/

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="https://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5zr5d5i/n1991/szw110/szh110/hoc09f/hbw0/hfc09f/cf100/hnce1ead6/fas30/fdi66/mqc000/mql15/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl15/mhw4/mhd98/mmc000/mml10/mmw1/mmd98/hhc00f/hhs2/hmcf00/hms2/hsv0" frameborder="0" width="110"
height="110"></iframe>
<div id="container">
  <h1>To-do List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
  <form id="task-list">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To-Do" id="task">
    <button type="submit"></button>
  </form>
  <ol id="sortable">
    <li id="task-EXAMPLE"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
      <label>EXAMPLE</label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

The first time this loads, there will be no storage, so we can read an examples from the HTML. As you will see, once you make an update, this will no longer be the case.

**Q:** Why the `<button>`?

**A:** `<form>` likes to have a submit button. It does not *need* it, yet having it will help a lot in ways I do not want to go into for this question.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").on("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    var $thatItem = $(event.target).parents("li");
    switch (event.target.nodeName) {
      case "SPAN":
      case "I":
        $thatItem.fadeOut(500, function() {
          $thatItem.remove();
          $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
        });
        break;
      case "LABEL":
        $thatItem.toggleClass("completed");
        break;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      updateLocalStorage($("#sortable"));
    }, 500);
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("#task-list").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Grabbing the text typed
    var todoText = $("#task").val();
    addListItem($("#sortable"), todoText, false);
    // Clear the text field
    $("#task").val("");
    updateLocalStorage($("#sortable"));
  });

  $(".fa-plus").click(function() {
    $("#task-list").fadeToggle();
  });
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function(e, ui) {
      updateLocalStorage($(this));
    }
  }).disableSelection();

  function addListItem($t, s, c) {
    //create a new LI
    var $li = $("<li>", {
      id: "task-" + s.replace(" ", "_")
    });
    if (c) {
      $li.addClass("completed");
    }
    var $wrap = $("<span>").appendTo($li);
    $wrap.append($("<i>", {
      class: "fa fa-trash"
    }));
    $li.append($("<label>").html(s));
    $li.appendTo($t);
    $t.sortable("refresh");
  }

  function updateLocalStorage($list) {
    var tasks = {};
    $list.find("li").each(function(ind, elem) {
      var task = $(elem).text().trim();
      var completed = $(elem).hasClass("completed");
      tasks[task] = completed;
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
      }
    });
  }

  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    if (localStorage.getItem("tasks") !== "undefined") {
      var localTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
      // Grab stored tasks
      $("#sortable").find("li").remove();
      $.each(localTasks, function(task, status) {
        addListItem($("#sortable"), task, status);
      });
    }
  } else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  }
});
```

You might see that there is very little of your original code left in here. There was just a lot of places to improve the code. I will discuss a bit briefly.

*Click Events*

---

Since we're basically listening for click events on the same parent, but want to do different things when specific elements are clicked, that are going to be dynamically created, we can make use of the `event.target` from the click event. If it's the `span` or the `i` that's clicked, we do one thing, if it's the `label`, another.

The `setTimeout` is just a way to create a delay in the operations from switch to updating. Otherwise the update will execute almost on top of the switch and will not see the changes to the list, this record no changes.

*Submit Event*

---

When you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> you're essentially submitting the form. Part of the reason to add a submit button. Instead of catching the keypress and trying to prevent this, why not just use the submit event to our advantage. This method will help on mobile browsers and such.

*Sortable Update Event*

---

When the list is sorted, and updated, we need to update that order in the local storage. Now is the time to do that.

*Functions*

---

I think these are pretty clear. You have an operation you will repeat many times, write a function.

*Get Item*

---

The last bit of code will load when the page is all ready. It will check for `localStorage` and check if there are `tasks` stored within. It will then populate the list with them.

**Q:** What's with the `JSON.stringify()`?

**A:** Yes, you can store stuff locally... only as String. This creates a string version of our object for storage.

Comment if you have other questions.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time on here I don’t really know how to make my post very good yet but I’ll try better

Comment: @GregMyers I hope that you got an answer to your question. If you did, and it was from here, I hope you go back and Mark one of the answers for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//check of spec
$("ol").on("click", "li", function(){
$(this).toggleClass("completed");

});

//click on X to delete To-DO

$("ol").on("click", "span", function(event){
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
  $(this).remove();
 });
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text'").keypress(function(event){
 if(event.which === 13) {
  //grabbing the text typed
  var todoText = $(this).val();
  $(this).val("");
  //create a new LI and add to UL
  $("ol").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText +"</li>")
 }
});

$(".fa-plus").click(function(){
 $("input[type='text'").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
h1 {
 background: #2980b9;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;

}

iframe {
 float: left;
}

ol {
 /* THE BULLET POINTS
 list-style: none;
 */
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 18px;

}

body {

 background-color: rgb(13, 168, 108);

}

li {
 background: #fff;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n){
 background: #d3d3d3;
}

span {

 height: 30px;
 width: 0px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
 opacity:0;
 background: #e74c3c
 

}

li:hover span {
 width: 30px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

input {
 font-size: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
 color: #2980b9;
 background-color: #e4e4e4;

}

input:focus {
 background: white;
 border: 3px solid green;

 /*OUTLINE OF INPUT BOX
 outlin: none; */
}

.fa-plus {
 float: right;
}


#container {
 
 width: 360px;
 margin: 60px auto;
 background: #d3d3d3;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);


}

.completed {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ToDo List</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="utd.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );

  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5zr5d5i/n1991/szw110/szh110/hoc09f/hbw0/hfc09f/cf100/hnce1ead6/fas30/fdi66/mqc000/mql15/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl15/mhw4/mhd98/mmc000/mml10/mmw1/mmd98/hhc00f/hhs2/hmcf00/hms2/hsv0" frameborder="0" width="110" height="110"></iframe>


 <div id="container">
  <h1>To-do List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
  <form id="task-list">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To-Do" id="task">
 </form>
  <ol id="sortable">
   <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> EXAMPLE</li>
   
  </ol>
 </div>

 

<script type="text/javascript" src="Utd.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
//check of spec
$("ol").on("click", "li", function(){
$(this).toggleClass("completed");

});

//click on X to delete To-DO

$("ol").on("click", "span", function(event){
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
 // $(this).remove();
 });
 //event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text'").keypress(function(event){
 if(event.which === 13) {
  //grabbing the text typed
  var todoText = $(this).val();
  $(this).val("");
  //create a new LI and add to UL
  $("ol").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText +"</li>")
 }
});

$(".fa-plus").click(function(){
 $("input[type='text'").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
h1 {
 background: #2980b9;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;

}

iframe {
 float: left;
}

ol {
 /* THE BULLET POINTS
 list-style: none;
 */
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 18px;

}

body {

 background-color: rgb(13, 168, 108);

}

li {
 background: #fff;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n){
 background: #d3d3d3;
}

span {

 height: 30px;
 width: 0px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
 opacity:0;
 background: #e74c3c
 

}

li:hover span {
 width: 30px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

input {
 font-size: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
 color: #2980b9;
 background-color: #e4e4e4;

}

input:focus {
 background: white;
 border: 3px solid green;

 /*OUTLINE OF INPUT BOX
 outlin: none; */
}

.fa-plus {
 float: right;
}


#container {
 
 width: 360px;
 margin: 60px auto;
 background: #d3d3d3;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);


}

.completed {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ToDo List</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="utd.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );

  </script>

</head>
<body>


 <div id="container">
  <h1>To-do List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
  
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To-Do" id="task">

  <ol id="sortable">
   <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> EXAMPLE</li>
   
  </ol>
 </div>

 

<script type="text/javascript" src="Utd.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so is there any way to make this to where i can save all the data to local storage?

Comment: local storage means in SQL SB ?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Jquery is client side scripting.using jquery it is not possible to data in SQL

Comment: so is there any way to do what i want to do or not/

Comment: you ca save this data in txt,excel,csv file

Comment: @SarikaKoli Greg is refering to HTML5 Web Storage: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

After making edits in browser, simply save the page as HTML with different file name. Your selected values will be saved.